# Regular Expression - Sed

Tags: regex, sed

How would I replace the commas following Four and Five with | but not those following One and Two ?

```
\"One,Two, Three\" Four, Five, Six

sed s'/,/|/'g
```

I would appreciate an answer that can be applied to any commas within the escaped quotes, not just this example.

Another example would be:

```
Mr ,Joe,Lish,,\"Acme, Inc.\",\"9599 Park Avenue, Suite 301\",Manhattan,NY,10022,\"\"\"6 A MAILING LIST MMBR GENERAL\"\"\"
```

Comment: In general this kind of thing is not a job for regular expressions because the language you are asking them to understand is *not regular*.

Comment: Correct. Regular expressions in general do not have *state* associated with the, which is what is required here. The parser needs to keep state information about whether it is inside of quotes or not.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `sed`:

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## Substitute '\"' with '\n'.
s/\\\"/\n/g

## If there is an odd number of '\"' or the string doesn't end with '\"' I 
## will append some at the end. There is no danger, but it will be used to
## avoid an infinite loop.
## 1.- Save content to 'hold space'.
## 2.- Remove all characters except '\n'.
## 3.- Remove one of them because next command will add another one.
## 4.- Put content in 'pattern space' to begin working with it.
## So, if in original string there were 3 '\"', now there will be 6. ¡Fine!
h
s/[^\n]//g
s/\n//
H
g

## Label 'a'.
:a

## Save content to 'hold space'.
h

## Remove from first '\n' until end of line.
s/\(\n\).*$/\1/

## Substitute all commas with pipes.
s/,/|/g

## Delete first newline.
s/\n//

## Append content to print as final output to 'hold space'.
H

## Recover rest of line from 'hold space'.
g

## Remove content modified just before.
s/[^\n]*//

## Save content to 'hold space'.
h

## Get first content between '\n'.
s/\(\n[^\n]*\n\).*$/\1/
s/\n\{2,\}//

## Susbtitute '\n' with original '\"'.
s/\n/\\"/g

## Append content to print as final output to 'hold space'.
H

## Recover rest of line from 'hold space'.
g

## Remove content printed just before.
s/\n[^\n]*\n//

/^\n/ { 
    s/\n//g
    p   
    b   
}

ba
```

Content of `infile`:

```
\"One,Two, Three\" Four, Five, Six 
One \"Two\", Three, Four, Five
One \"Two, Three, Four, Five\"
One \"Two\" Three, Four \"Five, Six\"
```

Run it like:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

With the following result:

```
\"One,Two, Three\" Four| Five| Six
One \"Two\"| Three| Four| Five
One \"Two, Three, Four, Five\"
One \"Two\" Three| Four \"Five, Six\"
```

Comment: The response is: undefined label 'a'

Comment: @adayzdone: Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem. My version is **GNU sed versión 4.2.1**, what is yours?

Comment: The version that comes with Mac 10.6.8

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 's/^/\n/;:a;s/\n\("[^"]*"\|[^,]\)/\1\n/;ta;s/\n,/|\n/;ta;s/.$//' file
```

Explanation:

- Prepend a newline to the pattern space. `s/^/\n/`
- Make a label `:a`
- Move a newline over either a string between quotes or a character that is not a comma. `s/\n\("[^"]*"\|[^,]\)/\1\n/`
- If the substitution  was a success loop to label. `ta`
- Substitute a `\n,` for a `|\n`. `s/\n,/|\n/`
- If the substitution  was a success loop to label. `ta`
- If no substitutions take place, all done so delete the newline. `s/.$//`

EDIT:

Actually any unique character or combination of characters can be used instead of `\n`:

```
echo 'Mr ,Joe,Lish,,\"Acme, Inc.\",\"9599 Park Avenue, Suite 301\",Manhattan,NY,10022,\"\"\"6 A MAILING LIST MMBR GENERAL\"\"\"' | 
sed 's/^/@@@/;:a;s/@@@\("[^"]*"\|[^,]\)/\1@@@/;ta;s/@@@,/|@@@/;ta;s/@@@$//'
Mr |Joe|Lish||\"Acme, Inc.\"|\"9599 Park Avenue, Suite 301\"|Manhattan|NY|10022|\"\"\"6 A MAILING LIST MMBR GENERAL\"\"\"
```

Comment: Looks like your version of sed doesn't allow newlines in the form `\n`. Try replacing all `\n` by `'"$'\n'"'` if using bash as your shell or insert real line feeds by typing CTRL-v return. Also see [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.1)

Answer (score 0):

There are lookahead and lookbehind operators for regular expressions. For example, the Javascript call

> bodyText = bodyText.replace(/Aa(?=A)/g, 'AaB');

will replace the text "Aa" with "AaB" if it's followed by another "A", leaving you with "AaBA". It won't match "AaB" because the "Aa" isn't followed by another "A". This is a lookahead call.

I believe the syntax for a lookbehind is ?<=.

So if these operators are supported by the package you're using, then you can use them to match a "," preceeded by "Four" or "Five" and only replace the ",".

Comment: @dmckee If you `alias sed="perl -p"`, then it will work fine. :)

Comment: @tchrist: You are a sick, sick person. But clever. And I mean that in a *good* way.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this one:

```
 echo '\"One,Two, Three\" Four, Five, Six' | sed 's/\(\("[^"]*"\)\?[^",]\+\),/\1 |/g'
```

which assumes a line is like

```
  [ ["someting"] word, ]* ["someting"] word
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I am on a Mac using Terminal if that changes anything.